# chromium browser not starting: Cannot open ELF file

Tags: chromium

```
pi@rp1:~ $ uname -a
Linux rp1 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

chromium-browser                      56.0.2924.84-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1000        armhf        Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
```

Chromium browser stopped working all of a sudden. When launching via command line i get the following message:

```
pi@rp1:~ $ chromium-browser
bootstrap_helper: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/nacl_helper: Cannot open ELF file!  errno=2
[1:1:0529/082248.901908:ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(315)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
[23412:23412:0529/082248.920011:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(495)] Failed to put Xlib into threaded mode.
[23412:23412:0529/082248.920551:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(272)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
[23412:23412:0529/082248.928215:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(272)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling the package and this fixed the issue a couple of times but it then stops working again.

Comment: Almost certainly a corrupt file or SD card. Can you reformat the SD card or use an other?

Comment: Yes I will give it a try and get back, thanks for feedback